# On a special continuous extension of Sylvester's Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

---

**Notations.** Denote by $S^{-}\left\{a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_m\right\}$ the number of strict sign changes in the indicated sequence $\left\{a_j\right\}_{j=0}^{m}$ of real numbers (i.e., when counting the sign changes, zero terms are discarded). Let $Z\left(f\right)$ be the number of zeros (counting their multiplicities as well) of a $C^{\infty}$ real-valued real function $f$ over its definition domain $\operatorname{Dom}\left(f\right)$.

---

One of J. J. Sylvesters's results can be formulated in the next

> **Theorem (Sylvester's classic result).** Let $\left\{\varphi_{j}\right\}_{j=0}^{m}$ be a sequence of strictly increasing real numbers and assume that the *polynomial*
>       \begin{equation}
> p\left(u\right) = \sum_{j=0}^{m} a_j  \left(u - \varphi_{j}\right)^{q},~u \in \mathbb{R}
> \label{eq:q_polynomial}
> \end{equation}
>       does not vanish identically, where $q\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}$ and the sequence $\left\{a_j\right\}_{j=0}^{m}$ consists of non-zero real numbers. Then,
>       \begin{equation}
> Z\left(p\right)
> \leq
> S^{-}\left\{a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_{m},\left(-1\right)^{q}a_0\right\}.
> \label{eq:Sylvester_s_classic_inequality}
> \end{equation}

The theorem above can be found, e.g., in:

- [J. J. Sylvester, 1908. *Collected mathematical papers*, Vol. II, Cambridge, p. 408];
- [Gy. Pólya, I. J. Schönberg, 1958. *Remarks on de la Vallée Poussin means and convex conformal maps of the circle*, Pacific Journal of Mathematics, 8(2):295$-$334, p. 299, https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1103040105];
- [S. Karlin, 1968. *Total positivity*, Vol. I, Stanford University Press, California, Lemma 3.1, p. 466].

---

**Question.** I would be interested in the validity of a special continuous extension of Sylvester's classic result. Can anyone either prove or disprove the next statement?

> **Statement to be proved/disproved.** Let $\left\{  \varphi_{j}\right\}  _{j=0}^{m}$ be a sequence of strictly
>   increasing real numbers and consider the *function*
>   \begin{equation}
> p\left(  u\right)  =\sum_{j=0}^{m}a_{j}\left(  \left(  u-\varphi_{j}\right)
> ^{2}\right)  ^{q+\alpha},~u\in\mathbb{R},\label{eq:q_alpha_function}%
> \end{equation}
>   where $q\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq1}$, $\alpha\in\left(  0,1\right)  $, while the
>   sequence $\left\{  a_{j}\right\}  _{j=0}^{m}$ consists of non-zero real
>   numbers. Then,
>   \begin{equation}
> Z\left(  p\right)  \leq S^{-}\left\{  a_{0},a_{1},\ldots,a_{m},a_{0}\right\}.
> \end{equation}

---

**Remarks.** Note that, for $\alpha \in \left\{0,1\right\}$, the statement in the question is true, since in these cases the function $p$ becomes a polynomial, and one can apply Sylvester's classic result for the even powers $2q$ and $2(q+1)$. The function $p$ is $C^\infty$ almost everywhere, which can make it difficult to study the higher order zeros of $p$. It would suffice to prove/disprove the statement by counting the zeros of $p$ as simple points (in the obvious geometric sense) over $\mathbb{R}$.

---

**Thank you for your time and energy for dealing with my question.**